# MySQL How to order by last name on a full name field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with a column called full name which contains "John Doe"

How can order the data by the last name that appears in the full name column ?

For a long name like "John Doe Second", I would like to order the data by the word "Doe".

I am using MySQL database.

EDIT: Here is the precision : Case "John" is impossible. What I consider as the last name should be after the FIRST space in my string.

Comment: where will last name appear in the string? after the first space, second space? you should clearly state that.

Comment: What about "Billy Bob Thornton"?  What about "Drake"?  Splitting full name into components is not a trivial problem at all.  The _right_ answer is to use multiple columns, spending as much time as needed cleaning up your data.

Comment: If you want to treat first name and last name differently (e.g. for sorting), then it should be two columns. Some problem names have already been mentioned. There are more. In Chinese names the surname comes first for instance.

Comment: I edited my post to give some precision. I assume there is no chinese name or anything else, just "classic" name which could contain "John Doe" or "John One Two". Nothing else.

Comment: If you really can't change the table and are fine with detecting the first space in your string, use string functions to find the position and  grab the substring you are interested in. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly. This I have at the moment : RIGHT(fullname, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(fullname)) - 1) ASC
But it does not work to order Joe Doe Second on "Doe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY SUBSTR(Name, INSTR(Name, ' '))
```

Comment: This answer to my question ! Thank you :)